# Trouble Deploying Old Gatsby Site To Gh-Pages

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, gatsby, github-pages

I am having an extremely difficult time deploying an old React website made with an earlier version of Gatsby.

One issue is that the site was originally built with node.js version 12, and it seems that it does not build at all with newer versions of node. For this reason I can't deploy it on Netlify.

I am now trying to deploy it on github pages, but it doesn't seem to be working properly...

I thought I added the necessary domain related things in the gatsby project code, but I guess not? Not sure what I am missing here...

https://evaluates2.com → doesn't recognize the site at all.

https://evaluates2.github.io/Evaluates2-Site/ → loading halfway with 83 errors.

https://github.com/Evaluates2/Evaluates2-Site → public repository containing all the code for the website.

Here are my DNS settings as well

[image]